# set convexity versus midpoint convexity.

Tags: proof-writing, convex-analysis

I'm tasked with the below question,

`Prove if true or give a counterexample if false: A set is convex if it contains the midpoint of any pair of its points.`

All resources I've found seem to talk about midpoint convexity, and I'm not certain of the difference between midpoint convexity and normal convexity. Additionally most questions I see talk about convex functions rather than sets.
My first inclination is that this is false, however I can't intuit why, or what a counterexample would look like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$S$ is  convex if $\forall x, y\in S$ , $(1-t)x+ty \in S, t\in [0, 1]$

i.e whenever $S$ contain two points, it must contains the entire line segment connecting those points.

(Special case : $t=\frac{1}{2}$)

$S$ is mid-point convex if $\forall x, y\in S$ , $\frac{x+y}{2}\in S$

Clearly a convex set is mid-point convex as for any two points $x, y$ , since $S$ contains the entire line segment joining $x$ and $y$ , it must contains the mid-point.

---

But a mid-point convex set is not necessarily convex.

For an example, $\Bbb{Q}$ is mid-point convex as the mid-point of any line segment connecting two rationals is again a rational. But $\Bbb{Q}$ is not convex set because irrationals are dense in $\Bbb{R}$.

---

One can show that a closed mid-point convex set is convex.

Hence for any closed set $S$ , $S$ is convex $\iff$ $S$ is mid-point convex. But for general $S$ the equivalence is not true.